# can't insert array to a state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm getting some weather data from an API through an async function. This function returns an array of objects that i want to set on a state, and when the state receives this array, i want to render the data.

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 'graficoEnergia': DIA,
      weather: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    
    async function setWeather(getWeatherFunction, address, component){
      const weatherArray = await getWeatherFunction(address)
      component.setState({
        weather: [...component.state.weather, weatherArray]
      })
    }

    if(!this.props.loading){
      setWeather(this.props.weather, this.props.doc.address, this);
    }

render() {
return etc
}
}
...
```

The function is in this.props.weather. i have also tried setting the state like this

```
weather: weatherArray
```

and

```
weather: component.state.weather.concat(weatherArray)
```

None of this sets the value to the state. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it supposed to supposed to be `this.setState({ weather: weatherArray })`

Comment: why you use `component.setState` and `...component.state.weather`, try `this.setstate` and `...this.component` , and use arrow function

Comment: did you log the `weatherArray` right before the `setState` to see if it has any contents ?

Comment: you don't need to use async in componentDidMount.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I did, and it has the array it should have. Even if I do something like this.state.array = weatherArray, and I log the state, the array is set, but outside the function it's not anymore.

Comment: There's really no reason to be passing `this` as an argument.. If you don't have access to ES6 arrow functions (which would be the preferable way) then you can bind the function to `this` using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

you should use `this.setState` to update state value

```
setWeather = async (getWeatherFunction, address) =>{
    const weatherArray = await getWeatherFunction(address)
    this.setState({
      weather: [...this.state.weather, weatherArray]
    })
  }
```

Comment: I'm passing "this" when i call setWeather function. The "component" parameter used inside the function is actually "this". This is working because i can console.log(component.state) and get all the data.